# Pythonic way to strip a string

Tags: python, xml, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to achieve a python equivalent of the following bash command:

```
VERSION=$( curl --silent "http://nexus:8080/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.xxx.yyy&a=zzz" | sed -n 's|<latestRelease>\(.*\)</latestRelease>|\1|p' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tail -1 )
```

I came up with the below snippet of code which does partially work and gets the bunch of       `<latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>` output, which is totally expected. However, I am stuck and want to get only 1.0.11 version as the output of the python script. Again `1.0.11` might differ depending upon the latest version in nexus, so would be nice if experts can suggest a dynamic solution to strip out the portion done in sed and tail part of bash in a pythonic way

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os;
import subprocess;
import re
import string;

proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "--silent", "http://nexus:8080/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.xxx.yyy&a=zzz"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
search_string = "<latestRelease>"
for line in out.splitlines():
if search_string in line:
    re.sub(r'\s*latestRelease\s*', '', line)
    print line
```

OUTPUT:

```
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
  <latestRelease>1.0.11</latestRelease>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: `1.0.11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has relevant libraries to help you with it:

- [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) - to make a request to the URL and get the XML data
- [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the XML results and get the `latestRelease` node value

Example (should work in your case but I have no way to test it working):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://nexus:8080/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.xxx.yyy&a=zzz'
tree = ET.parse(urlopen(url))
print tree.findtext('.//latestRelease')
```

Comment: A thousand times this.  You could also do it with `requests` followed by BeautifulSoup, or several other combinations, but any would be better than subprocess+curl+regex.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yeah, thanks, this helps me to advance in `regex` tag by providing `non-regex` solutions :)